# How to pass posts from two different sources to the same blade view but to be sorted by date

Tags: laravel, api, pagination, laravel-8, laravel-api

Headline seems a bit complicated but It's simple.
I have a Post model with table and everything, in the PostController I'm passing posts to the view as below

Here in my controller I'm getting my articles from API and passing it to $articles variable and I'm getting my posts from database and I'm passing it to $posts variable

```php
    public function index()
    {
        $articles = Http::withHeaders([
            'api-key' => config('services.devto.key'),
        ])->get('http://dev.to/api/articles/me/published');

        $articles = json_decode($articles, true);

        return view('posts.index', [
            'posts' => Post::latest()->filter(request(['search', 'category', 'author']))->paginate(6)->withQueryString(),
            'articles' => $articles
        ]);
    }
```

I can pass both to the same view and do as below and it works fine

```html
            <div class="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-3">
                @foreach ($posts->skip($posts->onFirstPage() ? 3 : 0) as $post)
                    <x-postCard :post="$post" />
                @endforeach
                @foreach ($articles as $article)
                    <x-articlepostcard :article="$article" />
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

This gives me 6 of my posts because i paginate them and then right after i get all 10 articles from my API and then in page 2 i get another 6 of my posts and below them the same 10 articles repeated again because i can't paginate them as they're just json in a variable.

Any ideas on how to make my view show posts and articles altogether paginated and sorted by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [data transfer object](https://twitter.com/mmartin_joo/status/1488896259482165249) that will represent a post or an article.

For instance *(assuming you're using PHP 8)*:

```php
class ArticleDTO {
    public __construct(
        public string $title,
        public string $content,
        public Carbon $published_at,
    )
    {
    }
}
```

Then, you fetch your articles and your posts, and you instantiate each of them into the DTO and make a collection out of it

```php
$articleCollection = collect();

foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $articleCollection->push(
        new ArticleDTO(
            $article->title,
            $article->content,
            $article->published_at
        )
    );
}

// Do the same for the posts
```

You can then pass the collection, sorted by date, to your view.

```php
return view('posts.index', [
    'articles' => $articleCollection->sortBy('published_at'),
]);
```

**Caveat to this solution**

In order to keep the pagination working, you might need to [manually invoke the paginator](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) but then you'll still load all the data on each request.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and let you know. Thank you so much for this but will infinite scroll be a better option in this case? or it's the same as pagination?

Comment: In my database I have different columns like user_id and category_id.. Do i have to create a different DTO for the data i'm getting from database?

Comment: For your first question, it won't change since both regular pagination and infinite scroll are a frontend matter and they rely on paginated results in the backend. 

One thing you could do is have a job that fetch the articles and store them in your posts table so that you have only one table to manage.

Comment: I will look into this and see if i can do it with google help. I've managed to successfully do the solution of using DTO and it worked but I faced an issue where all articles published next to each other and for some reason wasn't sorted by created_at. Maybe because the created_at format i'm fetching from API is different than the one created in my database. I'm thinking of giving up this and build a seperate section in frontend that contains the articles from API and another for the articles i publish on my site. Again thanks for helping out 

Comment: You can fix the sorting by date issue by making sure you cast the published time to a Carbon object so that both the article's dates and the post's dates are Carbon objects and can then be sorted anyway you would like. Refer to my example in the DTO, I make sure the `$published_at` is a Carbon object.

You're welcome and I hope you get to achieve what you'd like to do! :)